# IContactListProvider variable value is null on CD server

Tags: list-manager

We are fetching data from List Manager list. However, It is working fine for `CM` but the below code is throwing an error on `CD` server.

```
var contactListProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactListProvider>();
var contactProvider = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactProvider>(); 
var contactList = contactListProvider.Get(Guid.Parse(listId), new CultureInfo("en"));
```

When we try to run above code then `contactListProvider` value is null on CD.

Answer (score 1):

List Management services DI is configured for Content Management or Standalone Roles.
Please check configuration: **\App_Config\Sitecore\ListManagement\*.config**.
To enable the services for CD you need to patch **Sitecore.ListManagement.Services.config** config file for your CD role.

Comment: After adding patch file, getting this error "Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']" and I have added ContentDelivery role

Comment: That may be because in Sitecore.ListManagement.config the "ListManagement.Database is set to master and you do not have that on CD. Please review all ListManagement configs and make CD adjustments.